# Parte de la página se ve diferente en Firefox y en Chrome

Tags: bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

Me pasa una cosa extraña y es que hay una sola parte de la página que se ve diferente en Firefox y en Chrome. Es la distancia que hay desde el logo y el texto, en chrome es mayor y quiero que en Firefox sea igual pero sin embargo es menor.

Adjunto imágenes:
Chome:
[image: Chrome]
Firefox:
[image: Firefox]
Código:

HTML:

```
<section class="projectcontainer text-center col-md-12 center-block text-center">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 sidebar-outer">
    <div class="projectext">
      <p>Kunagise, reisisadama kõrvale ehitatud Saku Rock Hotelli siltide veidi teistmoodi tekstid ja kujundused. Ajalehepaberist võtmetasku. Hotelli logo ei ole meie kujundatud.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
    <div class="image_left">
      <img src="images/hotelli_do_not disturb_silt_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="web design app image";>
      <img src="images/hotelli_sildid_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="web design app image";>
      <img src="images/hotelli_sildid_2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="web design app image";>
      <img src="images/hotelli_votmekaardi_tasku.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="web design app image";>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
.projectext{
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.image_left{
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.projectcontainer{
    padding-top: 9%;
}
```

Sabéis si se puede arreglar de alguna manera?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿En qué resolución ocurre esto?¿Tienen los dos navegadores el mismo ancho?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro La resolución es 1920x1080 pero en pantallas más pequeñas como por ejemplo en la del portátil se nota aún más. La mediaquerie es la misma min-width 1200px

Comment: ¿Tiene alguno de los contenedores la clase `row`? No se ve en el código que compartes, ¿podría ser eso la causa?

Comment: No la clase row no la utilizo pero probé a añadirla ahora y pasa lo mismo :/. La web entera se puede ver aquí: clients.sabrinacouto.com/kiige. Ocurre en las páginas que se ven al pinchar en los círculos de la home. Quizás sea algo del menú?

Comment: He ido al enlace que compartes y he podido ver el problema. Parece que está relacionado con los padding de la imagen y cómo se computa el border-box (si quitas los padding, se ve igual en ambos navegadores)

Comment: Pero la imagen no tiene paddings, solo tiene un margin-left. Lo puse porque el texto tiene un position fixed para que al hacer scroll se siga viendo, si a la imagen le quito el margin el texto se pone por debajo de ésta.

Comment: Sí hay un padding para `.logo_menu`: padding-left: 8%; padding-top: 8%.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro pero si le quito los paddings al logo éste se me pega a los bordes de la pantalla. No hay otra manera de conseguirlo? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo usar normalize CSS para que tu pagina se resetee y se vea corracta en todo los navegadores modernos. https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 1):

Cada navegador administra el [css](/questions/tagged/css) a su preferencia y de acuerdo a su normatividad, para empezar te recomiendo des un "reset" a los estilos que tiene cada navegador por defecto,

```
*{
margin: 0;
pading: 0;
}
```

Con eso estas quitando todos los margenes y rellenos que pone cada navegador para cada elemento.

el `*` significa "A todos los elementos del HTML"

Espero te sirva la información.